# Exception when publishing mqtt message from lambda inside docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, mqtt, aws-iot

I am running a aws SAM Lambda inside a docker container, and am trying to publish an MQTT message using the pubSub class from aws's sample code (the aws iot SDK for JAVA). When I use the same class/method outside of a lambda, it works. when I run it from inside the lambda, I get the following exception:

software.amazon.awssdk.crt.CrtRuntimeException: aws_tls_ctx_options_init_client_mtls_from_path failed (aws_last_error: AWS_ERROR_FILE_INVALID_PATH(44), Invalid file path.) UNKNOWN(-1)

I thought this was because the docker container had no access to the certificates (.pem files) so I added that to the file sharing settings in the docker configuration, and still the same exception..
What am I missing here?

Comment: The `Invalid file path` error seems pretty clear; without more info (`Dockerfile` etc) its difficult to comment further.

Answer (score 0):

Like "Brits" was saying, the message is pretty clear. The certificate files are not recognized because the Lambda is running in a Docker container which has no access to the files on your local hard drive - including the certificates.
There are two solutions that can work:

1. Instead of using direct MQTT use MQTT Over WebSocket - Sig4, which uses IAM credentials instead of certificates.
   https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-java#build-the-sdk-from-the-github-source
2. Depending on your use case, it might even make sense to use HTTPS - IotDataPlaneClient to publish the messages instead of MQTT, especially if there could be concurrency issues with multiple Lambdas trying to use the same certificates. https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/iotdataplane/IotDataPlaneClient.html

What I ended up doing was option 1 - IDK if there is a way to include the files within the scope of the docker container, but this is a nice workaround.